# Sherlock themes not found after moving project to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, themes, actionbarsherlock

I have a former Eclipse project that was migrated to Android Studio / Gradle. Since I want it to be a "pure" Gradle project I created a new Android Studio project and moved the necessary files over there. Since then when I try to build the app I get the following errors in themes.xml file:

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. 
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\Christina\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Christina\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar -M C:\Users\Christina\AndroidStudioProjects\TheCatApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Christina\AndroidStudioProjects\TheCatApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\Christina\AndroidStudioProjects\TheCatApp\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Christina\AndroidStudioProjects\TheCatApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Christina\AndroidStudioProjects\TheCatApp\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.thecatapp -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Christina\AndroidStudioProjects\TheCatApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
Error Code:
1
Output:
C:\Users\Christina\AndroidStudioProjects\TheCatApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1190: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'.
C:\Users\Christina\AndroidStudioProjects\TheCatApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1256: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
```

Also, throughout my project in all classes where I have imported ActionBarSherlock the R file cannot be found: "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'". 
All this used to work fine before I moved my files to this new project.

This is how the themes.xml looks like:

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
</style>

</resources>
```

In build.gradle in my app this is how the dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

I have also tried to not declare the dependencies here and instead put them in the libs folder. Same result.

If I remove this row "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'" the errors disappear but when I try to run the app in my device I get this error:

[image]

Please help, what is the problem? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know the answer to my question.

The problem did NOT have to do with Sherlock themes or a missing R file.

The problem was that some libraries that I had imported to the file tree "collided" with somewhat similar ones that I added to the dependencies tag in the build.gradle file.

The "Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause:" error message shows up when this happens and more information can be found in the Gradle Console log.

I understand now that the preferred method is to add libraries under dependencies (like for example "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'9") rather than manually adding them to the lib-folder.